NGINX not showing index.php page, every other page works
I have the following code, tried so many attempts, 3 days working on it but still nothing. If I fix one thing, another breaks - looking for help.
What I'm trying to achieve:

example.com redirects to www.example.com
www.example.com/index redirects to www.example.com/
www.example.com/page.php redirects to www.example.com/page (remove .php)
www.example.com/resources should working if I have same folder and file name
www.example.com/sdfgdsgdfsgjdf shows 404.html because file doesn't exist
Params in url are working e.g ?lang=en&test=test
www.example.com// must have double slash disabled

Currently this code works except point 5. Every not existing page is showing index page.
I almost fixed all above by replacing try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args; with try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404; but then page www.example.com is not working, only www.example.com/index works
server {
    listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com/$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /404.html;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;
        }

    location @extensionless-php {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html/health-check;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri.html =404;
    }
}

So far I tried this many attempts to fix it in different order:
    # rewrite ^/$ /index;
    # rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    # rewrite ^(.+)/+$ $1 permanent;
    # rewrite ^(.+)/index.html$ $1 permanent;
    # rewrite ^/$ /index;

    # Too many redirects error
    # location = /index.php {
    # return 301 /;
    # }

    # try_files $uri /index.php;
    # try_files $uri =404;
    # try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    # try_files $uri /index.php?$args =404;
    # try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    # try_files $uri $uri.html @extensionless-php;
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args @extensionless-php;

    # Breaks folders and same file names
    # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    # Shows 404 on index page when ? in url
    # try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args =404;

    # Everything works except index
    # try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    # Breaks url
    # fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;


Try: try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php; in the location / block.

@RichardSmith tried and no. 4 is not working, including 404 page doesn't appear
